# how can I display 245276777556527592946 in scientific notation rounded to 13 significant digits?

Tags: computer-science, real-numbers, decimal-expansion, significant-figures

How to round 245276777556527592946 and can be represented in scientific notation? (13 significant digits, 12 after the decimal point)

Comment: $2.4527677755653\times 10^{20}$ or $2.4527677755653E+20$

Comment: I guess it should be  2.452767775565e20 as it is asked 12 digits after the decimal point, thanks.